# Finding gaps in concurrent date ranges - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, date-range

I have a table like the one below.  In reality there are 50,000 users, and a technically infinite number of ranges for each user.  There is no limit on date gaps, starts, ends, overlaps, etc.

```
User     From            To
A        2011-01-03      2013-04-09
A        2012-04-16      2012-03-08
A        2012-12-11      2013-06-17
A        2013-07-17
A        2013-09-22      2013-12-24
B        2011-04-06      2013-01-02
B        2012-02-12      2012-02-14
B        2012-11-10      2013-03-16
B        2013-04-16
B        2013-04-22
```

I need to calculate the number of weekdays in 2013 not covered by these ranges for each user.  The blank 'To' date means the range is ongoing.

In the example above it would be the number of weekdays between 2013-06-18 and 2013-07-16 for user A, and between 2013-03-17 and 2013-04-15 for B.

I have a lookup table of individual weekdays, but anything I do to the date ranges using min and max ends up giving me a 'solid' date range from 2013-01-01 to 2013-12-31.

I'm not bright....

Thank you.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Hi - Sorry, what's a DDL?  And sqlfiddle doesn't run at my work.  I can run other people's solutions, but not edit myown.  Possibly due to IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   users.User, COUNT(*)

FROM     users
           CROSS JOIN weekdays
            LEFT JOIN userDates ON
                        userDates.User  = users.User
                   AND  userDates.From <= weekdays.date
                   AND (userDates.To IS NULL OR userDates.To >= weekdays.date)

WHERE    weekdays.date >= '2013-01-01'
     AND weekdays.date <  '2014-01-01'
     AND userDates.User IS NULL

GROUP BY users.User
```

Comment: Thanks - I can alomost wrap my brain around that. Are you assuming a third table of usernames called 'users'? Can I ask why I need 'AND userDates.User IS NULL'?

Comment: @DazedandConfused: Yes, that's correct; if such a table does not exist, one could just put `(SELECT DISTINCT User FROM userDates)` between `FROM` and `users` above.  Filtering for `userDates.User IS NULL` leaves only those `weekday` records on which there was *not* a match in `userDates`: see [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).